# Deleting an option in a <select> list

Tags: javascript

i have following function:

```
function delete_auswahl()    
{

    var anzahl =document.getElementById ("warenkorbfeld").length ;

    for (var i =0; i<=anzahl; i++)
    {
        if (document.getElementById ("warenkorbfeld").options[i].selected==true)
        {



            if (document.getElementById ("warenkorbfeld").options[i].id == "Margherita" )
                gesamtbetrag = gesamtbetrag - 4;

            if (document.getElementById ("warenkorbfeld").options[i].id=="Salami"  )
                gesamtbetrag = gesamtbetrag - 4.50;

            if (document.getElementById ("warenkorbfeld").options[i].id=="Hawaii"  )
                gesamtbetrag = gesamtbetrag - 5.50;


            document.getElementById ("warenkorbfeld").options[i]=null;
            i--;// auf der gleichen stelle bleiben, da dass nächste feld nachrückt

        }
    }

    document.getElementById('gesamtbetrag').innerHTML=gesamtbetrag ;

}
```

before i added values with

```
function hinzu (pizza)
{
    NeuerEintrag = new Option(pizza, pizza, false, false);
    document.getElementById("warenkorbfeld").options[document.getElementById("warenkorbfeld").length] = NeuerEintrag ;

    if (pizza=="Margherita")
    {
        gesamtbetrag = gesamtbetrag + 4;
    }

    if (pizza=="Salami")
    {
        gesamtbetrag = gesamtbetrag + 4.50;
    }

    if (pizza=="Hawaii")
    {
        gesamtbetrag = gesamtbetrag + 5.50;
    }

    document.getElementById('gesamtbetrag').innerHTML=gesamtbetrag ;

}
```

now, in the delete function doesn't substract the price.
despite this, all works.

what's wrong with this term?

```
if (document.getElementById ("warenkorbfeld").options[i].id == "Margherita" )
                gesamtbetrag = gesamtbetrag - 4;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've got the problem, it was

if (document.getElementById ("warenkorbfeld").options[i].value=="Salami"  )

options.**value**

not

options.id

now it works :-)

Answer (score 2):

Where does the `gesamtbetrag` variable come from? You're subtracting from it but it looks like it doesn't get defined until afterward.  I think you may need to add

```
var gesamtbetrag = document.getElementById('gesamtbetrag').innerHTML
```

To the top of your function.

Also, consider the following optimisations for your code:

- you don't need the `for` loop to iterate over the options (`for (var i =0; i<=anzahl; i++)`, you can use the `selectedIndex` property of the select element instead.
- Use `select.remove()` instead of `select.options[i] = null`.
- Make use the subtraction assignment operator `-=` to subtract a number for the variable.
- Reduce `getElementById` lookups by storing the element in a variable instead.
- You could compare the `selectedIndex` to a known index (e.g. `sel.selectedIndex == 0`) instead of comparing `selectedOption.id == "Some string"`.  I haven't done this below because I don't know your indexes

```
function delete_auswahl()    
{
    var gesamtbetrag = document.getElementById('gesamtbetrag').innerHTML;
    var selEl = document.getElementById("warenkorbfeld");
    var opt   = selEl.options[selEl.selectedIndex];

    if (opt.id == "Margherita")
        gesamtbetrag -= 4;
    else if (opt.id=="Salami")
        gesamtbetrag -= 4.50;
    else if (opt.id=="Hawaii")
        gesamtbetrag -= 5.50;

    selEl.remove(selEl.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: i solved it, (option.value not option.id)  :-)

thanks your post was usefull :)